# "A treaty was signed ......... three countries." 'Between' or 'among'?

Tags: between-among

Usage of *between* and *among* and their limitations

Comment: What do you think is correct and why?  And why do you find this confusing?

Comment: Hint -- 'between' usually infers two...

Comment: Better: Three countries signed the treaty. Three countries were signatories of the treaty. I would forget both between and among: both are irrelevant here. A treaty was signed BY three countries.

Answer (score 1):

I would say neither is correct.  Agreements (treaties, wills, mortgages) are always signed BY the party or parties.  "A treaty was signed by three countries."

"The treaty sets forth trade quotas and limitations BETWEEN the countries."

"AMONG similar treaties, the treaty BETWEEN these three countries is unique in that all have populations under 12 people."